# CreateProcessWithLogonW : unable to start process

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-7, windows-services

Hi I am completely new to programming. And please someone help me.

I am trying to start a pocess from a service. 
I need to start the new process by prompting user to enter admin credentials.

I was trying to use `CreateProcessWithLogonW()`.

Am I using the right function. 
I tried to give input username, password, domain as localhost. I gave full pathe to the .exe file that i need to start.

Here is the piece of code.

```
CreateProcessWithLogonW(L"Administrator",
                        L"localhost",
                        L"password",
                        0,
                        NULL,
                        L"c:\myupdates\myapp.exe",
                        NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS | CREATE_CONSOLE,
                        NULL,
                        NULL,
                        &si,
                        &pi);

Si.cb = sizeof(si);
Si.lpDesktop = L"winsta0\\default";
```

But the process never started. Can you guys tell me what I am doing wrong.
And what do I need to do to promt user to enter credentials of administrator instead of hardcoding it.

Comment: What does `GetLastError()` say?

Comment: One thing you are doing wrong is assigning to the `si` structure after you call `CreateProcessWithLogonW`. You should do it before.

Comment: Is it me, or is proper usage of the Windows API `CreateProcessWithLogin()` and "I'm completely new to programming" somehow seem a little unnerving...

Comment: I was assigning si structure before making this call. Does this function promts the user to enter the Administrator credentials

Comment: Did you check the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms682431%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of the very function you're calling? What does it say about admin-prompting?

Comment: Something else to keep in mind from the documentation: "Windows XP with SP2 and Windows Server 2003: You cannot call CreateProcessWithLogonW from a process that is running under the "LocalSystem" account, because the function uses the logon SID in the caller token, and the token for the "LocalSystem" account does not contain this SID. As an alternative, use the CreateProcessAsUser and LogonUser functions."

Comment: lpDomain should probably be NULL rather than L"localhost" for a local account.  (The documentation says that the username must be in UPN format if lpDomain is NULL, but AFAIK the UPN format for a local account is just the username.)  You should also note that in Windows 7 the process will not be visible, because it will be launched in a non-interactive session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of CreateProcess* functions will do any promting. They are low level APIs and know nothing about GUI.

If you want user to be prompted, use `ShellExecuteEx` with `runas` command. Windows will first ask a permission to elevate and then prompt for credentials.

Comment: Keep in mind that this is being done from inside a service, which runs in its own desktop, and `ShellExecuteEx()` has no provision for running a new process in another desktop.  You need to use a `CreateProcess...()` function for that. If you need to run an elevated process, try [`CreateProcessElevated()`](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista-security/UAC__The_Definitive_Guide.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

One problem is passing a string literal as the command-line argument, as that argument must be modifiable. From [`CreateProcessWithLogon()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms682431%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in relation to the command-line argument:

> The function can modify the contents of this string. Therefore, this parameter cannot be a pointer to read-only memory (such as a const variable or a literal string). If this parameter is a constant string, the function may cause an access violation.

You also need to escape the backslashes. Change to:

```
WCHAR cmdLine[] = L"c:\\myupdates\\myapp.exe"; /* 'cmdLine' is a
                                                  copy of the string
                                                  literal. */
```

and pass `cmdLine` instead.

After any WINAPI function failure check [`GetLastError()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms679360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as it will inform you of the reason for failure.

Comment: Can you suggest me how to pass the path executable instead string literal

Comment: I have tried the changes you gave, but the process did not start. I tried to capture last error, I got back with no: 3221225477

Comment: @Vivek That is an access violation (C0000005). At least one of your parameters to the API is not only setup incorrectly, it is setup for *catastrophy*. [**Please** read and follow the documentation *and* sample code on the documentation page.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682431(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to escape the program string properly as well:

```
L"c:\myupdates\myapp.exe"
```

should at least be:

```
L"c:\\myupdates\\myapp.exe"
```

Frankly, there are a multitude of things wrong with this code, from improper setup of SI, to the parameters passed to the API itself. I suggest you read up more.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's too late to help you. But it might be helpful for others, though. If you use the `CreateProcessWithLogonW` function and you are using the `Default` desktop just keep `lpDesktop` as NULL.

If `lpDesktop` is not Null you have to enter the user's sid (getting with `LookupAccountNamean`) as a `ACE` in desktops and winstation's `DACL`

So here are the steps you have to do to add an `ACE` for a desktop:

1. get Desktop handle with `OpenDesktop`, use the right dwDesiredAccess
2. get the `Security Descriptor` with `GetSecurityInfo` and `DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION`as securityinfo
3. get the `DACL` from your `Security Descriptor`
4. Add `AddAccessAllowedAce`with the sid of your User's sid
5. Set the modified `DACL` to your Desktop handle

now repeat those steps for `winsta0` winstation

The commantary of Mr. Furious in the [documantary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682431%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) helped me alot to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The access violation is down to the lpCommandLine parameter. That is meant to a editable memory, LPWSTR and the API function does modify the buffer. But you pass a pointer to non-modifiable memory.

But there's a more fundamental problem. You say you want to prompt for credentials from a service. Services should not show UI and in modern versions of Windows, a service simply cannot show UI. Your design is flawed and you need to re-consider it.